# Cannot open excel file on sharepoint site

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise

I have a library on a sharepoint site which includes some excel files. When I click the excel file, it shows this error:

```
Sorry, we couldn't find your license to use this feature. If you know who manages the licenses for your organization, tell them you'd like a license to use 'Excel Services'.
```

The server has "SharePoint Server with Enterprise Client Access License". The enterprise features are enabled. And the client also has Office Professionla Plus 2013 license.

What else can cause this error?

Thanks

Comment: Did you enable the feature also on the existing site?

Comment: yes, it is enabled.

Comment: try to run this `enable-spfeature -url http://yourSite/ -identity PremiumSite -force`